# DateTime.TryParseExact returns true if date string matches format string

Tags: c#, datetime

Ran into an issue when running a unit test to ensure the correct response from an api when an invalid datetime format sting is passed in. When passing in a date string as "0711" and format "0711", the api was not returning an error and instead set this date to today.

With eg the examples below - DateTime.TryParseExact() returns true setting the date to today.

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("1019", "1019", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out result)

DateTime.TryParseExact("1a111", "1a111", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out result)
```

If the strings do not match
eg

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("1019", "1018", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out result)
```

this correctly returns false.

Is this expected behaviour? If so can canyone explain the internal workings?
What is a reliable way of mitigating this other than just checking to see if the strings match eachother?

Comment: Per the [fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings): "All other characters are always interpreted as character literals and, in a formatting operation, are included in the result string unchanged. In a parsing operation, they must match the characters in the input string exactly; the comparison is case-sensitive."

Comment: Try to pass correct format string DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm", enUS, 
                                 DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))

Comment: [Furthermore](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact), "If `format` defines a date with no time element and the parse operation succeeds, the resulting `DateTime` value has a time of midnight (00:00:00). If format defines a time with no date element and the parse operation succeeds, the resulting `DateTime` value has a date of `DateTime.Now.Date`." Therefore, a string with neither time nor date elements will always parse to `DateTime.Now.Date`, if it parses at all.

Comment: @gabba - unfortunately I dont control the format string - it is passed in from an external location that may contain bad data - hence running tests to ensure this is picked up and dealt with appropriately.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: neither the format nor the "date"-string defines a valid date(with or without time). But the parse succeeds if both are same.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: the documentation does not explicitly say what happens in the case of a custom format string with neither date nor time components, but the case for a missing date *and* time seems a logical extension of the rules for a missing date *or* time.

Comment: Look at following three samples. The first returns `true`(`Date.Today`), the second `false` and the third even throws an exception: `bool b01 = DateTime.TryParseExact("XXXXX", "XXXXX", null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out result);
            bool b02 = DateTime.TryParseExact("What's This", "What's This", null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out result);
            bool b03 = DateTime.TryParseExact("NO_Date", "NO_Date", null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out result);`

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Both of your example strings contain format specifiers. Try calling `.ToString` with them.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The `s` for example is preserved as the second identifier. That one is matched and should hold a numeric value, which it doesn't.

Comment: The conclusion from all of this: you cannot use `DateTime.[Try]ParseExact` to validate format strings, or else you must accept that strings like `1019` are *technically* valid format strings (and let the caller live with that).

Comment: @JeroenMostert: you don't use `DateTime.TryParseExact` to validate format strings but the datetime-string passed. It suprised me that it cannot be used for that always and that this method can even throw exceptions at runtime if you pass the wrong format string(`ArgumentException` if it's for example `_` or `IndexOutOfRangeException` if they are f.e. `NO_Date`). So `TryParse` is not safe in any case.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: The question specifically is about (purported) invalid format strings ("when an invalid datetime format sting is passed in"), not about the validity of the strings parsed by them, so that's what I assumed the OP to be doing. I will agree that `TryParseExact` throwing an exception is a bug in any case (or at least something that makes the API far less useful). It's certainly not documented to do so (other than for an invalid `DateTimeStyles` argument) and that might warrant [opening an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this expected behavior?

Yes.

> If so can anyone explain the internal workings?

The numbers you put in are just read as literals, and they do match. There is no `HH`, `mm` or similar identifiers in your parse string, so there is no actual date to parse. It defaults to `DateTime.Now`.

> What is a reliable way of mitigating this other than just checking to see if the strings match each other?

Use an actual date time format string, like `HHmm`.

Comment: Thank you! - the issue is I dont control the string being passed into the api

Comment: Where is this documented? This is clearly not a valid `DateTime`. Why it is treated like one and returns `DateTime.Today` for any literal passed? Why the  parse operation succeeds at all?

Comment: See the comment of Jeroen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48225571/datetime-tryparseexact-returns-true-if-date-string-matches-format-string#comment83432708_48225571. It is not a valid date time, but the string does conform to the parse rule. The defaults just kick in now. @Tim

Comment: I undertand - so if my date strong was "9920180112" and my format string could be "99yyyyMMdd" for example which would reject the date "9820180112"
the "99" on the front just being a string literal match

Comment: @TimSchmelter it's a perfectly valid `DateTime`. The format says "use defaults for every component of the date and time" and a `DateTime` with defaults for every component is valid. It's a *useless* parse, but the rule allows us to deal with fixed-representation components such as the `T` in ISO 8601 formats, so the general mechanism is very useful indeed.